# Display a number as a product of its prime factors

Tags: c++, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded, primes, factors

### Task:

Link to original problem :https://www.spoj.com/problems/FACTCG2/

> The task in this problem is to write a number in a multiplication of
>   prime 
>       numbers separated by “`x`”. You need to put the number 1 in this multiplication.
>
> #### Input:
>
> The input consists of several lines.
>
> Each line consists of one integer N (1 <= N <= 10^7) .
>
> #### Example Input:
>
> ```
>            1
>            2
>            4
>            8
> ```
>
> #### Example Ouput:
>
> ```
>            1
>            1 x 2
>            1 x 2 x 2
>            1 x 2 x 2 x 2
> ```

### My approach:

I pre-compute an array `Primes` which contains the smallest prime factor of every number from 1 to 1e7 using the sieve.  Then to find the answer , I divide the number given in each query by its least prime factor until it becomes '1' or a prime number. Then I display it.

The code works for small inputs but SPOJ gives me time limit exceeded. I think maybe the vector in `factorise` function has 
            something to do with it. I tried printing the answer without storing it in vector but 'x' makes it difficult .

### My code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
vector<long long>Primes(1e7);
bool prime(long long x)
{

    for(int i=2;i<=sqrt(x);i++)
    {
        if(x%i==0)
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
void least_prime_factor()   //To store least prime factor of a 
                             //  given number
 {

    Primes[1]=1;
                    for(int i=2;i<=1e7;i++)
                    {
                            if(Primes[i]==0)
                            {
                               Primes[i]=i;
                               for(int j=2;i*j<=1e7;j++)
                                {
                                    if(Primes[i*j]==0)
                                    Primes[i*j]=i;
                                }

                             }
                    }

 }
vector<long long>factorise(int x)  //This is to store the factors 
                                   //of a number 

{
    vector<long long>ret;
    while(x!=1||prime(x)!=true)
    {
        ret.push_back(Primes[x]);
        x=x/Primes[x];
    }
return ret;
}

int main() {


least_prime_factor();
int n;
while(scanf("%d", &n) == 1)
if(n==1)
{
    cout<<"1"<<endl;
}
else{

    vector<long long>ans=factorise(n);
    cout << "1 x" ;
    for(int i=0;i<ans.size();i++)
    {
        if(i==ans.size()-1)
            printf(" %d ", ans[i]);
        else
            printf(" %d x", ans[i]);
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you please indent your code in a more readable/consistent way?

Comment: Your factorize function is incorrect.You assume that Primes[x] is a divisor of x for any x.

Comment: @UmNyobe - and how is that not the case, given how `Primes[]` is populated?

Comment: See https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/205291/13680 for some factorisation goodies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't include `<bits/stdc++.h>` - it's not standard, and on platforms that provide it, it drags in far too much.

Don't `using namespace std` - this namespace is not designed for wholesale inclusion, and can produce subtle bugs when its names overload your own.

Don't use a floating-point number such as `1e7` when you want a simple integer `10'000'000`.

Don't compute `std::sqrt(x)` every time around the loop - save the value as an integer for faster comparisons.

Use unsigned types for unsigned arithmetic.  Given that inputs (and therefore factors) are no greater than 10⁷, we can get away with `std::uint_fast32_t` rather than `long long`.

Although the code claims to use a sieve, every input number is inefficiently tested for primality without reference to the sieve (multiple times, even).

Why use a `std::vector` rather than `std::array` for something whose size is constant and known at compile time?  Also, why write the size in two places (which need to be consistent) instead of simply using `Primes.size()`?  (Also, fix the off-by-one error where we overstep the end of the vector).

I recommend using C++ streams, rather than mixing C buffered I/O and forcing the two libraries to repeatedly flush each other.

Avoid global variables - `Primes` can be a local static member (perhaps with an immediately-executed lambda expression as initializer).

Why not always include `1` as the first result, rather than have to add that in the printing code?

---

To dive in to one function in particular, let's pick on `least_prime_factor()`.  Apart from the misleading name, we're doing a lot more work than we need to here.  Every time around the loop, we're multiplying `i` by `j` (a good compiler will hoist the three `i*j` into a single computation, and reuse that), but we could simply be adding `i` each time.

A standard improvement to naive sieves is to observe that every multiple of a prime *p* that's less than *p*² also has smaller factor than *p*, so once we've marked *p*, we can jump straight to *p*² before striding by *p* thereafter.

Apart from the first pass (which marks even numbers), we can stride by 2 *p* each time (knowing that we've already marked even numbers).  We can take that further with a wheel of factors, but even this is reducing the work by a factor of two.

Let's see what we have now:

```
// Create an array populated with the smallest prime factor of each
// number, or 0 for primes (and unity).
void least_prime_factor()
{
    Primes[1]=1;
    // First, mark all the even numbers; this allows us to halve the
    // work for all other primes.
    for (std::size_t i = 2;  i < Primes.size();  i += 2) {
        Primes[i] = 2;
    }

    for (std::size_t i = 3;  i < Primes.size();  ++i) {
        if (Primes[i]) { continue; }

        Primes[i] = i;
        for (std::size_t j = i * i;  j < Primes.size();  j += 2 * i) {
            if (!Primes[j]) {
                Primes[j] = i;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That's noticeably less work, and if we also replace `prime()` with a simple lookup in `Primes[]`, then we'll have a much more efficient program.

Answer (score 4):

I'll add :

- Why not using your `vector` in your `prime(...)` function?
- Using `std::endl` sending a `'\n'` and then flushes the output buffer. So `std::endl` is more expensive in performance.
- Since `least_prime_factor` can be computed at compile time, maybe try to make it `constexpr` (plus use an `std::array` for `Primes`).
- You mix out outputting functions from `<iostream>` (`std::cout`) and from `<cstdio>` (`printf(...)`); try to be coherent.
- Instead of printing `"1 x "` (and then conditionally `"N x "` for each value, or `" N"` if it's the last), just print `"1"` (and then, unconditionally print `" x N"` for each)
- You can print result directly from `factorise` instead of `ret.push_back(Primes[x]);`, so you avoid returning a vector by value and iterate over it.
- Don't mix types, neither in comparison operations nor in arithmetic operations. Here, you have `long long`, `int`, `double` (as the result of `sqrt(..)`, but also with `1e7`) and `unsigned int` (`vector::size()` return a `vector::size_type` which is an `unsigned int`). Mixing signed and unsigned, integer and floating point, in arithmetic or comparison is a very bad idea.

And, yeah, try to space your code, it'll help readability.

note: I fixed indent in your code for a more readable, but it seems you rejected :/

Answer (score -3):

First of all you are using cout and asking for TLE help !!!. You need to remove cout first from your code Also i can see that you use local vector array assignment in our main function. Local vector allocation is time consuming. Try to avoid this too.

Comment: The comment is simply wrong. std::cin and std::cout can be quite performant. Most certainly they are not the reason for TLE

Comment: Though i am not regularly solved problem now but i can ensure this, there are so many problems in spoj only changing cout/cin to printf/scanf can cause TLE to AC.